# Rails app Query params and Cookie based login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session-cookies

I am trying to find a way to distribute a Ruby on Rails app selectively by sending them an email with the link that logs them in. This should be the only way to get to the page hosted at a unique subdomain. Additionally, we don't plan on having a login wall so the access would need to be guarded by using Cookies or the Query URL params.

A couple of questions regarding this:

1. Is it possible to leverage cookies exclusively to achieve this? I.e Any way to embed cookies within the URL sent in the email itself?
2. An approach I felt that might work is to embed the user ID (encrypted) in the URL in the email. In order for the users to not need to bookmark this URL or go back to the email to access this link, I was planning to store their session ID via a browser cookie. Any issues with this approach?
3. How to avoid wandering users(i.e users who haven't received this email) to access this page (i.e a nice way to raise a 404 error)?

Any other cleaner ways to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to leverage cookies exclusively to achieve this? I.e
> Any way to embed cookies within the URL sent in the email itself?

No. You cannot "embed cookes in a URL". Cookies are set via the SET-COOKIE header in a response or through JavaScript.

> An approach I felt that might work is to embed the user ID (encrypted)
> in the URL in the email. In order for the users to not need to
> bookmark this URL or go back to the email to access this link, I was
> planning to store their session ID via a browser cookie. Any issues
> with this approach?

Yes. You should generate a random token thats not tied the users id.

> How to avoid wandering users(i.e users who haven't received this
> email) to access this page (i.e a nice way to raise a 404 error)?

Create time limited access tokens that can only be used once by the user. There really is no other way for you to actually know that the person requesting the URL is the recipient of the email.

What you are describing can be accomplished with [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) which is a pretty good community tested point of reference if you want to reinvent the wheel.

When you invite a user Invitable creates invitation tokens which are stored in the users table. This is just a random string. There are also timestamp columns that expire invitations automatically.

The token is included in the URL in the invitation email as a query parameters.

When the user clicks the link the controller looks up the user based on the token and nulls `users.invitation_token` so that it cannot be used again. This stores the user id in the session and takes the user to a screen where they edit and finalize their account by setting a password.

Comment: thanks for sharing Devise Invitable. The page I am trying to guard is a search tool and doesn't contain sensitive data so when the user accesses this URL, they wouldn't be asked to create a password. 

Since the URL is a persistent link to the tool and not really an 'invitation'. Is there a lighter weight alternative?

Comment: How do you really expect this to provide any degree of security if the only thing resticting access is the knowledge of the URL?

Comment: I totally agree that this isn't a super secure experience but we intend for this link to not be distributed around and not be restricted until we add a login wall. Is there a simpler way to achieve this use case?